# Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Am trying to connect to MySQL database using the below code.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'pass',
    database : 'my_db',
    insecureAuth : true
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

But am getting the below error :

> Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support
>   authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL
>   client

I have MySQL-installer-community-8.0.11.0 installed on my local.

Do I need to install any other connectors to connect to the database?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/

In the doc, it's said

> `MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD`: When the variable is true (which is its
>   default state, unless `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is set or
>   `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD` is set to true), the root user's password
>   is set as expired and must be changed before MySQL can be used
>   normally. This variable is only supported for MySQL 5.6 and later.

Try setting `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` for your docker environment. 
You also may need to change auth mode for your user.

```
> mysql -u root -p

ALTER USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Worked for me.

Edit :
To check what auth is set:

```
SELECT user, plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'username';
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem yesterday with my docker container with mysql + nodejs.
I didnt found so far a fix but it has something todo with the new mysql version(8.X).
After i reinstalled mysql with version 5 everything worked well for me.

Comment: Can confirm. Same here.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL(8.x) connection works fine if we choose legacy password encryption of MySQL(5.x) during MySQL(8.x) installation. If i choose strong password encryption with Mysql(8.x) during installation its not working.

Comment: You probably need to fix your grammar here, In the second statement are you trying to say that it doesn't work if choose legacy password encryption of MySQL(5.x)?

Comment: Nope am telling it works if we choose legacy password encryption of MySQL(5.x).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this solution worked for me:

1. Go to your MySQL workbench and click on your current database.
2. In the Navigator window (on the left), click `Users and Privileges`.
3. Click `Add Account` at the bottom of the user list.
4. Give it another login name (e.g. `node_test`).
5. **Set the Authentication type to `Standard`.**
6. Set `Limit to Host Matching` to localhost.
7. Set a new password (e.g. `coding-is-awesome`).
8. Here's what your resulting code should look like:

   ```
   var mysql = require("mysql");

   var con = mysql.createConnection({
     host: "localhost",
     user: "node_test",
     password: "coding-is-awesome"
   });

   con.connect(function(err) {
     if (err) {
       console.log("Failed to connect");
       throw err;
     } else {
       console.log("Connected!");
     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the insecureAuth : true line and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the MySQL2 npm package

`import mysql2 from 'mysql2';`